# Slave with more databases than master

Tags: mysql, replication

I have two servers. Lets called ServerA and ServerB each has their own database server and web server. Those two servers are used to run different website. ServerA data is more important because it deals with money transaction. While ServerB is running a blog-like website which is less important.

I am looking for live backup solution for my ServerA. (Currently I do full-backup for ServerA once per day). Right now, I want to try Master-Slave backup. ServerA will be "Master" and ServerB will be "Slave".

**Question**
ServerA (Master)
 - DatabaseA

ServerB (Slave)
 - DatabaseA (Sync with Server A)
 - DatabaseB (Unique to ServerB, it is used for blog-like website)
 - DatabaseC (Unique to ServerB, it is used for blog-like website)

Web application in ServerB will not touch DatabaseA. ***I know it is possible to do this, but I want to know if it is a wise solution for me given that I do not have enough budget to purchase another server for backup.***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common setup.
If it is *wise* in your case is hard to tell, this depends on the workload of the servers, the connection between them, the database size, the amount of queries it processes, etc.

Since you write that DatabaseA is used for money transactions there is also the security consideration.
If you run insecure applications on ServerB a compromise of one of those could get an attacker closer to your important application.

Your post mentions that you want to use this setup as a Master-Slave *backup*.
I hope you mean this in the way that you will run `mysqldump` (or similar techniques) on the slave server.

A Master-Slave setup is **NOT** a backup solution!
Imagine that your application has a bug or gets compromised and drops your most valuable data.
The drop statement will be replicated and wipes your "backup" instantly (more or less) as well.

Answer (score 0):

If server B is doing a dump or backup then it could be a backup solution, also server A would never feel the load of a backup. We do this on high demand servers, so that they are never slowed down during a backup.